# Access rights to delete the branches in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

How to assign some group to delete the branches under project in gerrit. Currently only admins can do this.

I have added Owner access on branch pattern below. This seems to work but not sure, if this is correct way of doing it

What all additional capabilities that this OWNER access will add.

can some one throw some light on this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're searching for the "Delete Reference" permission. See more details in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_delete).